# How to import data from sqlite using python-docx?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, python-docx

**Requirement:**

I need text and image data from sqlite3 db to be populated into a word doc.

**What I'm doing:**

I'm using python-docx library, [using this documentation to get started](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

**Db structure:**

CREATE TABLE Users(UserID integer PRIMARY KEY, UserName text NOT NULL, UserImage Blob)

**My code:**

```
import sqlite3
from docx import Document

document = Document()
document.add_heading("Test Report from Sql",0) # ---> Document heading name
connection = sqlite3.connect("demo.db")  # ---> Connection to Db
cursor = connection.cursor()
rows = cursor.execute("SELECT UserName FROM Users where UserID = 1") # ---> Trying to get text values from db and adding
p = document.add_paragraph(rows)

connection.close()
document.save('Report1.docx')
```

**Error Message:**
TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not tuple