# Python libraries to import data from sqlite to word doc

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, ms-word

I have data stored in sqlite database (text & images) and want this to be imported into a .doc/.docx format. I am using the below references to try and achieve the same.

1. [Python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
2. [docx-mailmerge](http://pbpython.com/python-word-template.html)

Both the above have documentation, but not any content for sourcing the data from sqlite db.

Look forward to your feedback on if these are the best libraries for the job? Would be very grateful if you could direct me to any documentation that serves the required purpose.

**EDIT:** 
To avoid downvotes for lack of research effort, [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254894/how-to-import-data-from-sqlite-using-python-docx). This question is only to understand if there are other good alternatives to the one I'm currently using. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite is part of Python Standard Library. Here is a link to a [concise tutorial](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_sqlite_in_python_tutorial.html) on how to use it. 
Below is a short excerpt:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlite_file')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create a table
c.execute('CREATE TABLE {tn} ({nf} {ft})'\
    .format(tn='my_table', nf='name', ft='VARCHAR'))

conn.commit()
# insert table
c.execute("INSERT INTO {tn} ({cn}) VALUES ('test')".\
    format(tn='my_table', cn='name'))
conn.commit()
# select rows
c.execute('SELECT * FROM {tn}'.format(tn='my_table'))
all_rows = c.fetchall()

for row in all_rows:
    # do something
```